# This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have windows 7 64x professional Laptop , then i download a new VM on it , but when i try to mount an ISO imag for windows server 2008 i got the following error :_

**This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.
This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'

(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Workstation.

(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

For more detailed information, see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.**

**So what is causing this error?**

Comment: *So what is causing this error?* - you've **definitely** checked the obvious idea that the error message means what it says and says what it means and that your BIOS settings need to be configured as described above?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is my first VM instaltion , so i would like to know if these is any supporting documentations of how i can solve this issue?

Comment: There's a decent enough explanation on the vmware knowledge-base article that you've included above as to what's going on and what to do. Beyond that, none of us can tell you what precisely how to do it for your laptop because this is going to be something that's specific to the BIOS in your computer rather than some standard we can rattle off for you that will work everywhere.

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark - perhaps enable VT...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do what the man said: Enable VT-X in the Bios.
Sometimes it is also called Hyper-V.
(For some obscure reason it often is hidden in the "security" section of the Bios.)

Most computers ship with the setting disabled by default.
Some computers (especially laptops) are technically capable of VT-x but the Bios doesn't show it so you can't enable it.
In that case you are sheer out of luck.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, but i can not figure out how i can enable this on Intel core i7 on windows 7 64x  on an HP laptop?

Comment: By reading the manual, or searching the fine Google

Answer (score 3):

I get this error every time my Windows 7 Dell desktop restarts after a windows update. My CPU does support vitualization, and the BIOS is properly configured, but somehow the restart puts it in a weird mode.

Simple shut-down, and power on fixes the problem.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. Please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps). Lack of reputation does not stop you asking a question.

Comment: A windows update did trigger the problem for me too, but shutting-down/powering-on did not fix the problem on an HP pro laptop. I had to re-enable virtualization in the BIOS, as it had been somehow disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Go to BIOS by pressing ESC on powering on.
Go to System Configuration -> Device Configuration or similar
Check the enable VT-x
Save
Power cycle
Should work

Answer (score 0):

You should  check  the intel website to see if your processor supports VT-X/ Hyper-V

If Intel says it has VT-X... try upgrading the BIOS/enable it.