# This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Running VMware Workstation 12 on Windows 10 and I'm getting the below error message when trying to launch a Linux install. This was working previously but for some reason It's stopped. Also note I went into the BIOS and found virtualization disabled (not sure how that happened) but it's still not working. I've been trying to see how to disable 'trusted execution' but I don't see that anywhere. Also, I have an ASUS BIOS.

Here is the error message:

[image: Error in Screenshot when I try to launch the VM]

> This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems.
>   However, 64-bit operation is not possible.
>
> This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
>
> Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the
>   BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since
>   changing this setting.
>
> (1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and
>   disable 'trusted execution.'
>
> (2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings
>   have been changed.
>
> (3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing
>   VMware Player.
>
> (4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

Comment: Provide the exact make/model of computer. Not just “asus bios”

Comment: You enabled Intel VT-x and POWERED OFF?  Not restart.

Comment: Ahh! That's it. I only restarted!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible](https://superuser.com/questions/593973/this-virtual-machine-is-configured-for-64-bit-guest-operating-systems-however)